# Get Root URL/Domain Name in Email Template

Tags: python, django

I'm using django's send_mail to send out an email (using a template) that has the following line in it:

To reset the password, please click the link below:

```
http://localhost:8000/{% url 'reset_password' uid=uid token=token %}
```

as you can imagine, this isn't ideal. I have multiple environments (local, staging, dev, prod), each with an entirely different base URL. I want to be able to dynamically generate the domain name, but the url function only provides the path after the root URL (i.e., /reset_password/some_token/).

Is there any way I can dynamically generate the host name? I know I could have an environment variable on each of my machines and put that in my settings.py file, but I'm not the only developer, and our environments may not be able to be updated for a while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly what the [sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/#getting-the-current-domain-for-full-urls) is designed for. The domain name will be stored in the database of the environment and can be edited from the admin interface. You can pass this domain name into the context of your template. For an example:

```
>>> from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
>>> Site.objects.get_current().domain
"example.com"
```

Comment: When I do this on my localhost, I literally get "example.com". Is this expected behavior? How can I get it to return the domain it's currently running on -- localhost:8000?

Comment: That's the default value. That's why you need to set it correctly in each environment programmatically or using the admin.

Comment: What's the best way to accomplish this? Simply setting Site.objects.get_current().domain inside of settings.py?

Comment: The [django documentation suggests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework) using an initial data fixture.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom template tag for this.

```
# myapp/templatetags/mytags.py
from django import template
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def current_domain():
    return Site.objects.get_current().domain
```

Then, In your template, us it like this:

```
{% load mytags %}
http://{% current_domain %}{% url 'reset_password' uid=uid token=token %}
```

Comment: When I do this on my localhost, I literally get "example.com". Is this expected behavior? How can I get it to return the domain it's currently running on -- localhost:8000?

Comment: That's because the default value of site domain is set to example.com. You can change it using the admin panel.

Comment: Also refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework

Answer (score 0):

Beginning with django version 1.5, you are required to define an `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting for authorized access to your website. As this varies by deployment, it can be useful in this case:

```
from django.conf import settings

# <trimmed> ...

class User(AbstractUser):

    # <trimmed> ...

    def get_url_notifications(self):
        return settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS[0] + reverse('user-notifications')
    url_notifications = property(get_url_notifications)
```

Here, I have added a `url_notifications` property to the `User` model that returns a full URL to a view in my django site.

And, in `settings.py` on each deployment, you have:

```
# settings.py

# ...

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['production.example.com', ]
```

Works great!